# Mongoose: Multi find() in forEach - Where is final then()

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, es6-promise

I use multi find() to populate 'categories' and 'pic' for 'post'. But I don't know Where is the data returned finally in full to 'res.send(posts)'.
Or use another method, 'Promise.all' for example, Please help me solve the problem

```
Post.find().then(posts=> {
   async.forEach(posts, function(post, done) {
        Cat.find().where('posts').in([post.id]).then(categories=> {

            post.categories = categories;

            var id=mongoose.Types.ObjectId(post.id);
            File.findOne({'related.ref': id}).then(pic=>{
                post.pic=pic;

            });
        })
    //res.send(posts);????
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use **async-await** for your route handler:

```
async (req, res) => {

  const posts = await Post.find()

  for (post of posts) {

    const categories = await Cat.find().where('posts').in([ post.id ])

    post.categories = categories

    const id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(post.id)

    const pic = await File.findOne({ 'related.ref': id })

    post.pic = pic

  }

  res.send(posts)

}
```